# Updatepanel trigger postback in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, updatepanel, postback

I have the next gridview:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upCustomer" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCustomerSearch" EventName="Click" />
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvPersons" EventName="PageIndexChanging" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCode" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnCustomerSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnCustomerSearch_Click" />
    <asp:GridView ID="gvPersons" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"
        PageSize="10" GridLines="Vertical" EmptyDataText="No results"
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" OnRowDataBound="gvPersons_RowDataBound"
        OnPageIndexChanging="gvPersons_PageIndexChanging"
        onselectedindexchanging="gvPersons_SelectedIndexChanging">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Personid" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Nombre" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Telefono" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
        </Columns>
        <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" Position="TopAndBottom" />
    </asp:GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
```

I need the next funcionality:

- When I click btnCustomerSearch, I want an Ajax update (works)
- When I click pagination, I want an Ajax update (works)
- When I click a row (gvPersons_SelectedIndexChanging), I want a **postback** update, but this doesnt work.

Is posible to get an asyncpostback in some events in a gridview and postback in anothers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a Button inside your update panel and define a *PostBackTrigger* for it

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upCustomer" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <Triggers>
        ...
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="PostBackButton" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        ...
        <asp:Button ID="PostBackButton" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="PostBackButton_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Insert a *TemplateField* on your grid like this

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <input type="button" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('<%= PostBackButton.ClientID %>',<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>)" value="Select" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

When the user clicks on any button inside the grid, we will have to manually fire the *Click* event of the *PostBackButton* passing the *RowIndex* as argument.

On the server side

```
protected void PostBackButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string argument = Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
    gvPersons.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(argument);
}
```

Now we just have to hide the *PostBackButton*...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    PostBackButton.Style.Add("display", "none");
}
```

...and disable the event validation of the page, otherwise we will get an *ArgumentException* when the user selects a row

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ... EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

Yes. It is possible.

Comment: Well, I made some changes of your answer, but this really works very good. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers), you can try this

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCustomerSearch" EventName="Click" />
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvPersons" EventName="PageIndexChanging" />
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="gvPersons" EventName="SelectedIndexChanging" />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: System.Web.UI.PostBackTrigger' doent have the property 'EventName'

Comment: and you can't register an AsyncPostBackTrigger and PostBackTrigger on the same Control